# How can I run a Python script without any permission?

Tags: python, linux, bash, unix, sandbox

I want to run a Python script and don't let the interpreter do any of these things:

1. File I/O (read, write, delete, etc)
2. Execute external processes (such as a bash command)
3. Have access to the internet
4. Create more threads

I want to run untrusted Python scripts and I don't want to run anything that can possibly ruin my computer. They are only allowed to use lists, string operations, arithmetic, arrays, and such (i.e. basic stuff enough for algorithms).

I can preprocess scripts to delete any import. But removing imports isn't enough because functions like `open()` (opens a file) are still available. I already managed to control CPU and memory usage.

Is there a command or program to change the Python interpreter to only be able to read the `script.py` (so it can execute it) and then not have any other permission to do absolutely anything?.

Comment: some elements can be controled by creating user with different privilages - ie. without access to other folders - and running as this user.

Comment: maybe you could run in Docker or other Virtual Machine which doesn't have access to real machine.

Comment: @furas that's one feasible option, but I've read that some hacks have been demonstrated that can break the container and gain access to the rest of the computer. Maybe docker combined with another layer of protection would work well.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysandbox/ maybe? "By default, untrusted code executed in the sandbox cannot modify the environment (write a file, use print or import a module). But you can configure the sandbox to choose exactly which features are allowed or not, eg. import sys module and read /etc/issue file."

Comment: In general you should never use blacklisting (e.g. stripping `imports`) as a security mechanism - there'll always be some tricky edge-case you missed that a malicious user can figure out. See also [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: May I ask why you would run a program that you appear to have absolutely no trust in?

Comment: @JefréN. it's supposed to be an application for people in my school to learn Python. Code is tested and the backend sees if the output of the program is correct. It has more functionalities, but the code comes from random users in the internet, that's the problem. But as I said, I only want to allow algorithmic code (strings, arrays, etc) so if there's a tool that can restrict a process, then that'd work (such as allowing only a pipe to stdout, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. +! Would it be possible for you to delete some of the packages you don't want them to be able to use? For instance, `os`, `threading`, etc? (This being done in conjunction with running their scripts as a limited user.)

Comment: I also recommend researching ways to prevent this *under-privileged* user from using the network ... ?

Comment: There’s (full) seccomp, though that might be too restrictive. I’d go with a VM, probably (start up a snapshot, run the script over SSH, discard the VM). http://www.skulpt.org/ might also be an option.

Comment: @JefréN. there are quite a few online applications that let you run code inputted by some user, take http://pythontutor.com as an example of that.

Comment: actually, @FeloVilches taking a look at [pythontutor source code to see how they set limits on resources.](https://github.com/pgbovine/OnlinePythonTutor/blob/master/v3/pg_logger.py#L66)

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: Totally unrelated but I love the humor in your 'About Me' section. :)